# Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.IGeolocator.GetPositionAsync IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Estou utilizando o Xamarin.Forms e tentando pegar a posição com o Plugin.Geolocator e metodo GetPositionAsync cai numa excessao de IndexOutOfRangeException

```
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

        CancellationToken cancellation = new CancellationToken(false);

        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 1;

        if (!CrossGeolocator.IsSupported)
            position = new Position();
        if (!CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationEnabled)
            position = new Position();
        if (!CrossGeolocator.Current.IsGeolocationAvailable)
            position = new Position();

        try
        {
            position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1), cancellation, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            position = new Position();
        }


System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  at (wrapper stelemref) System.Object.virt_stelemref_object(intptr,object)
  at <StartupCode$NInterpret-Xamarin-Droid>.$Interpreter.push@3149 (NInterpret.Interpreter this, System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1[T] callStack, System.Object x) [0x00028] in <5b4cad727eef0f2aa745038372ad4c5b>:0 
  at NInterpret.Interpreter.interpretBlock (System.Object[] args, System.Object[] locals, Mono.Cecil.Cil.Instruction initialInstruction, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpSet`1[T] inTries, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] lastException) [0x00225] in <5b4cad727eef0f2aa745038372ad4c5b>:0 
  at NInterpret.Interpreter.interpret (System.Object[] args) [0x00098] in <5b4cad727eef0f2aa745038372ad4c5b>:0 
  at NInterpret.Interpreter.callAMethod (NInterpret.AMethod m, NInterpret.AType[] ptypes, NInterpret.AType[] genericMethodArgs, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] genericArgsIndex, System.Object[] args, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] byRefArgs, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1[T] byRefTarget, System.Object target, System.Boolean virtualCall) [0x00183] in <5b4cad727eef0f2aa745038372ad4c5b>:0
```

Abraço e Obrigado

Comment: Onde está a declaração de `position`, quais são os arqumentos de `GetPositionAsync()` e seu tipo de retorno. Você tem certeza de que o erro é nesse trecho de código?

Comment: Olá Leandro, tudo bem?
O getPositionAsync está sem parametros e o retorno é Position.

            Position position;

            CrossGeolocator.Current.DesiredAccuracy = 100;

            try
            {
                position = await CrossGeolocator.Current.GetPositionAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
                position = new Position();
            }